# apache2 proxypass for neo4j webadmin

Tags: neo4j, mod-proxy

I'm trying to get my Neo4J admin running through `mod_proxy`, so that I can add a password. The instructions on http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/security-server.html seem clear, and I followed them.

The new webadmin seems to be working on `http://[my-domain]/neo4jdb/webadmin/`. But queries do not get executed.

I've also opened the Neo4j server to other IP-adresses, and now on `http://[my-domain]:7474/webadmin/`, everything works fine, including the querying.

The lines in `apache.conf` are

```
ProxyPass /neo4jdb/webadmin/ http://localhost:7474/webadmin/
ProxyPassReverse /neo4jdb/webadmin/ http://localhost:7474/webadmin/
```

What am I missing here? There are no errors in the browser console, the button just doesn't do anything.

Comment: maybe you can debug the AJAX request to get some more information with the debugging console in Chrome, to get some more insight into what is happening?

Comment: the exact same thing happens to me. It looks like the ajax does not get through.

Comment: I had installed neo4j and apache though cookbooks. Now with the default debian install everything works ok.